# How to compose URL for AJAX in Adminhtml Magento 1.9

Tags: adminhtml, url, ajax, paths

I'm inside the Admin area, I'm adding a check inside the products, inside my File phtml write:

```
<?php $ajaxUrl = Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/MyCompany_MyModule_AjaxController/check'); ?>
```

This is real path

```
\http\app\code\local\MyCompany\MyModule\controllers\ajaxController.php
```

This is the Function inside file phtml

```
function check(element) {
    new Ajax.Request('<?php echo $ajaxUrl ; ?>', {
    method:     'get',
    onSuccess: function(transport) {
        alert('Sent notification.');
    },
    onFailure: function(transport) {
        alert("Couldn't send a notification. ");
        console.log(transport);
    }
});}
```

This is inside my controller:

```
    public function checkAction()
{
    $value= 'example';
    Mage::app()->getResponse()->setBody($value);
}
```

and this is my config.xml

```
    <admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <MyCompany_MyModule before="Mage_Adminhtml">MyCompany_MyModule</MyCompany_MyModule>
                    <MyCompany_MyModule after="Mage_Adminhtml">MyCompany_MyModule_Adminhtml</MyCompany_MyModule>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Premise, the ajax call works but I always get 404 error back
I'm pretty sure the paths are wrong,
but I can not understand how to set them up, can you help me?
thank you

Comment: Your controller file name should be AjaxController.php and same for class last word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <MyCompany_MyModule before="Mage_Adminhtml">MyCompany_MyModule_Adminhtml</MyCompany_MyModule>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
```

And controller file should be at: **http/app/code/local/MyCompany/MyModule/controllers/Adminhtml/AjaxController.php**

```
<?php

class MyCompany_MyModule_Adminhtml_AjaxController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function checkAction()
    {
        $value= 'example'; Mage::app()->getResponse()->setBody($value);

    }
    protected function _isAllowed() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

You need to put this code for URL. `<?php $ajaxUrl = Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/ajax/check'); ?>`

Comment: Nothing I wrote the suggested changes but it still does not work, error 404

Comment: unfortunately nothing has changed, I do not understand

Comment: I have updated answer. with this `<?php $ajaxUrl = Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/ajax/check'); ?>`

Comment: Welcome! Please accept answer so it will help to others.

Answer (score 1):

Path http\app\code\local\MyCompany\MyModule\controllers\Adminhtml\AjaxController.php

```
<?php 
class MyCompany_MyModule_Adminhtml_AjaxController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action {
public function checkAction()
{
    $successCode = 1;
    Mage::app()->getResponse()->setBody($successCode);
} 
}
```

Config.xml

```
            <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <MyCompany_MyModule before="Mage_Adminhtml">MyCompany_MyModule_Adminhtml</MyCompany_MyModules>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
```

Ajax Call

```
<?php $ajaxUrl = Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/MyCompany_MyModule_AjaxController/check'); ?>

function check(element) {

new Ajax.Request('<?php echo $ajaxUrl; ?>', {
    method:     'get',
    onSuccess: function(transport) {
        alert('Sent notification.');
    },
    onFailure: function(transport) {
        alert("Couldn't send a notification. ");
        console.log(transport);
    }
}); }
```

URL Generated

```
https://localhost/index.php/admin/MyCompany_MyModule_AjaxController/check/key/b800cc33b4822a6b866056ef0094cee4/?isAjax=true&&form_key=emruvSXuKs9r7Bic
```

Status Code 404